# Why does it not work to overload "operator <<" on std::string?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, overloading

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template
<
    typename CharT,
    template<typename> class Traits,
    template<typename> class Allocator,
    typename RightT,
    typename StringT = basic_string
    <
    CharT,
    Traits<CharT>,
    Allocator<CharT>
    >
>
enable_if_t
<
    is_constructible<StringT, RightT>::value,
    StringT&
>
operator <<(StringT& lhs, const RightT& rhs)
{
    return lhs.append(rhs);
}

int main()
{
    string s1, s2;
    s1 << s2; // compilation error!

    return 0;
}
```

My compiler is VS 2015 Update 3. The compilation error message is:

> error : invalid operands to binary expression ('string' (aka
>   'basic_string, allocator >') and
>   'string')

Why does it not work as expected?

Comment: This is exactly what `operator +` is for

Comment: No. It is not same as `operator +`, but similar to `operator +=`. However, `operator <<` can do: `s1 << s2 << s3 << ...`, while `operator +=` cannot.

Comment: @xmllmx Why are you trying to overload this using a template actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I want to handle two cases, e.g. `std::string` and `std::wstring`, in one template function.

Comment: @xmllmx The template parameter should probably be `char_t` then, and you take a `std::basic_string<char_t>` as parameter types primarily.

Answer (score 4):

Did the compiler give you any more info than that single line?  Something like:

```
26:1: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
35:11: note: couldn't deduce template parameter 'CharT'
```

If you replace

```
operator <<(StringT & lhs, const RightT& rhs)
```

with

```
operator <<(basic_string<CharT, Traits<CharT>, Allocator<CharT>>& lhs, const RightT& rhs)
```

it compiles.

Basically you are putting the cart before the horse.  You can use template args to form a default template arg (`StringT = ...`) *if* you already know the template args.  You can't use the default to determine the args.

If you want to support both `basic_string` and other/custom strings, you may need to write two specializations or something.

Or realize what your template requirements really are - you don't require Constructible, you require "Appendable", so SFINAE on that, and ignore whether it is a basic_string or MyCustomString - it doesn't matter; the only thing that matters is whether `lhs.append(rhs)` works (and, uh, maybe figure out its return type as well...)